# data.table return multiple rows

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to return multiple columns for some groups in data.table. I use a function to separate a list of values and compute a vector for each group. I'd like to return these values for a table like this

```
address1, time1, value1
address1, time2, value2
address1, time3, value3
```

I group time1-time2 in a function and would like to return something like this

```
address1,sum(value1),       mean(value1)                     (by timegr1)
address1,sum(value2+value3),mean(value2+value3)              (by timegr2)
```

I managed to compute all the values, just cannot format the results, so that it'd put the two time-groups in different lines and keep the sum and mean in the same line.

EDIT
here is the code:

```
v <- data.table(address =c(1,1,1,1),time=c(1,50,51,52),value=c(1,2,3,4))

fun <- function(time,value) {
data <- data.table(time=time,value=value)
#this split depends on a number of criteria
k <- split(data,c(0,rep(1,nrow(data)-1))) 
k1 <- sapply(k,function(x) c(mean(x$value),sum(x$value)))
return(k1)
}

v1 <- v[,fun(time,value),by=address]
```

V1 comes out as

```
   address V1
1:       1  1
2:       1  1
3:       1  3
4:       1  9
```

I really need something like

```
   address  mean sum
1: 1        1    1
2: 1        3    9
```

thanks a lot.

Comment: Please provide code to create an actual `data.table` for us to work with.

Comment: Your word example has `address`, `timept` and `value` referenced but your example data.table only has two columns, none called any of these. Please either change your word description or the data.

Comment: thanks, updated the code. hope it's clearer now.

Comment: I've read this a few times and I still don't follow. The trouble is the example data only has one group (`address=1`) so it's hard to see what you're after, as @Jake said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This old question already has an accepted answer. However, the answers seem not to reproduce the expected result as shown in the question or appear overly complicated, IMHO.

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to group the data by `address` and by a function which depends on `time`. The computation of the grouping variable can be done on the fly in the list expression passed to the `by` parameter. It is not necessary to create a separate `group` variable beforehand or to use `split()` within a function.

With the current CRAN version 1.10.4-3 of `data.table` the solution is a one-liner:

```
v[, .(mean = mean(value), sum = sum(value)), by = .(address, timegrp = (1:nrow(v)) == 1L)]
```

> ```
>    address timegrp mean sum
> 1:       1    TRUE    1   1
> 2:       1   FALSE    3   9
> ```

OP's expected result does not contain the second grouping variable. This might has happened just by chance because of the apporach the OP has chosen. However, if removal is required, this can be achieved as follows:

```
v[, .(mean = mean(value), sum = sum(value)), by = .(address, timegrp = (1:nrow(v)) == 1L)][
  , timegrp := NULL][]
```

> ```
>    address mean sum
> 1:       1    1   1
> 2:       1    3   9
> ```

Alternatively, `time` can be grouped by

```
v[, .(mean = mean(value), sum = sum(value)), by = .(address, timegrp = time %/% 10)]
```

> ```
>    address timegrp mean sum
> 1:       1       0    1   1
> 2:       1       5    3   9
> ```

Answer (score 3):

To return multiple rows, the function being applied by data.table should return either a vector or list of vectors, as in the example below.

```
library(data.table)

(dat <- data.table(expand.grid(sub=1:4, score=1:4), key="sub"))
#     sub score
#  1:   1     1
#  2:   1     2
#  3:   1     3
#  4:   1     4
#  5:   2     1
#  6:   2     2
#  7:   2     3
#  8:   2     4
#  9:   3     1
# 10:   3     2
# 11:   3     3
# 12:   3     4
# 13:   4     1
# 14:   4     2
# 15:   4     3
# 16:   4     4

dat[,list(stat=c("mean","sd"), value=c(mean(score),sd(score))),by=sub]
#    sub stat    value
# 1:   1 mean 2.500000
# 2:   1   sd 1.290994
# 3:   2 mean 2.500000
# 4:   2   sd 1.290994
# 5:   3 mean 2.500000
# 6:   3   sd 1.290994
# 7:   4 mean 2.500000
# 8:   4   sd 1.290994
```

Comment: Okay, in that case `v[,list(mean=mean(b),sum=sum(b)), by=a]` gets you close to what you want, although it doesn't match exactly your desired output because the example doesn't really make sense. I.e., how is the `data.table` supposed to know to aggregate the a=1 rows into a single row, but for some reason to aggregate the a=2 rows into *two* separate rows like you have it arranged in your example? If all you specify in the `by` parameter is `a`, then it is going to aggregate completely according to `a`. More information is needed in the table to get your desired output.

Answer (score 1):

I could only achieve this in two steps

```
fun <- function(x) {
    c(0,rep(1,length(x)-1)) 
}

v <- data.table(address =c(1,1,1,1),time=c(1,50,51,52),value=c(1,2,3,4))

v1 <- v[,group:=fun(time),by=address]

v2 <- v1[,list(mean=mean(value),sum=sum(value)),by=list(address,group)]

   address group mean sum
1:       1     0    1   1
2:       1     1    3   9
```